# How to detect different types of collisions in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I have two different types of collisions I want to detect in SpriteKit:

When ballOne hits goalOne and when ballTwo hits goalTwo:

So far I've added my different physics categories:

```
struct physicsCategory {
    static let ballOne :UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
    static let goalOne :UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    static let ballTwo :UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
    static let goalTwo :UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
}
```

And here's the relevant parts of my class:

```
class gameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var borderBody:SKPhysicsBody!

    var myscore:Int = 0
    var opponentScore:Int = 10

    override func sceneDidLoad() {

        super.sceneDidLoad()
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    }

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        let firstBody = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode
        let secondBody = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode

        if ((firstBody.name == "ballOne") && (secondBody.name == "goalOne")) {
            collisionGoalOne(BallOne: firstBody, GoalOne: secondBody)
        }

        else {

        }
    }

    func collisionGoalOne(BallOne: SKSpriteNode, GoalOne: SKSpriteNode) {
        addScore()
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        let touch = touches.first
        let touchLocation = touch!.location(in: self)

        let ballOne = childNode(withName: "ballOne") as! SKSpriteNode
        ballOne.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCategory.ballOne
        ballOne.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsCategory.goalOne
        ballOne.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategory.goalOne
        ballOne.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

        let goalOne = childNode(withName: "goalOne") as! SKSpriteNode
        goalOne.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCategory.goalOne
        goalOne.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsCategory.ballOne
        goalOne.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategory.ballOne
        goalOne.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false        
    }

}
```

Right now the app crashes when the ball collides with the wall on

`let firstBody = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode`

with "Could not cast value of type 'appName.gameScene' (0x105320) to 'SKSpriteNode' (0x1877b5c)."

Would love to understand why this crash is happening and if this is even a good approach to collision handling. Thank you.

Comment: `touchesMoved` is the wrong place to be setting up your physics bodies. Have you created a physics body for the wall you mention - it's not in the code you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

FirstBody might not be able to be cast to SKSpriteNode, so only create that variable after you check which nodes collide.

Note that ballOne could be either bodyA or bodyB so change your code to check for both possibilities.

I changed your code a bit. Hope this helps

```
if ((contact.bodyA.node?.name == "ballOne") && (contact.bodyB.node?.name == "goalOne")) {  
     let firstBody = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode
     let secondBody = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode
     collisionGoalOne(BallOne: firstBody, GoalOne: secondBody)
 } else if ((contact.bodyA.node?.name == "goalOne") && (contact.bodyB.node?.name == "ballOne")) {
     let firstBody = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode
     let secondBody = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode
     collisionGoalOne(BallOne: secondBody, GoalOne: firstBody)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a couple of changes you might want to make.

When your ball node contacts the wall, I believe your `didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)` method is invoked with one body as the ball (`SKNode`) and the other body as the scene border (`SKScene`).

Forcing a cast of SKScene to SKSpriteNode with `let firstBody = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode` crashes, as [RT5754](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5940124/rt5754) points out.

To fix this you might consider the following:

1. Add a physics category for the wall/border.  Something like:

   ```
    static let sceneBorder :UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
   ```
2. Update the border and the ball nodes to have collision physics:

   ```
   ballNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsCategory.sceneBorder
   borderNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsCategory.ballOne + physicsCategory.ballTwo
   ```
3. When handling other contact logic, my pattern for 
   `didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)` 
   is like this:

   ```
   func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
     var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
     var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

     //in did begin contact, order the bodies by physics category
     if firstBody.categoryBitMask > secondBody.categoryBitMask {
       let temp = secondBody
       secondBody = firstBody
       firstBody = temp
     }

     //logic to handle contact is based on physicsCategory
     if secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.whatever {
       methodToHandleWhatever(thingOne: firstBody, thingTwo: secondBody)
     }
   ```